# What is the optimal value for x in a 1-1000 random number generator 2 stage algorithm where x is the "split point".

Tags: optimization, random, coupon-collector

I would like a mathematical answer to this.  If I have a random number generator algorithm (let's say 1 to 1000), and I simply pick a random number over and over until I see each of the 1000 possible numbers at least once, as we get closer and closer to 1000 unique numbers seen, finding the next one not yet seen becomes more and more difficult and thus takes more time (with the last few "needed" being the most difficult and most time consuming).  For example, if we have already seen 980 unique random numbers, then we only have a 20 in 1000 chance of choosing the last "missing" random number to complete all 1000.

To possibly save time (by making it easier for the algorithm to find the last few random numbers needed), suppose at some point (for example, after seeing 750 of the random numbers), we instead just copy those 250 remaining unseen numbers to some array (a list of nonseen numbers), and then just generate a random number between 1 and 250 (for example) until all of those are seen, and then merge the results with the first part (750+250=1000).

So my question is, to save the most time (assuming it takes little to no time to make the split, vs. the major time wasted trying to find the last few numbers in the 1-1000 scheme), using x as the split position (in the above example, x=750), what is the optimal split position mathematically speaking so that the fewest number of "collisions" (picking the same random number more than once) happens.  That is, choose a single value of x such that the # of collisions is minimized.  For simplicity, we will say you can only split the 1-1000 scheme once.  My guess is it might be optimal somewhere between 500 and 750 but I wonder mathematically what the correct answer is.

A computer simulation solution might not be helpful because of caching and other factors, but a computer program to count up the number of random number events and # of collisions would be useful, minimizing those.

While people are "chewing" away at this mathematically, I may write a computer program to count up the # of random numbers generated, and # of collisions, and try to optimize it (by trying every possible split position between perhaps 500 and 900).

Food for thought but not part of the question:  If for some reason 500 is the correct answer, then I wonder if splitting those again (such as 4 groups of 250 numbers) would be even better.

Just to give you a "feel" for what is happening here, I wrote a quick computer program and found that for an array of size 1000, I am seeing on average about 7500 calls to the RNG (Random Number Generator) function, of course about 6500 of them (1000 less) being collisions.  I ran this 1000 times and got an average.  So we are at a 86.7% collision rate (6500/7500) to get all 1000 random numbers this way.

Note that if I stop after finding only 750 unique random numbers (the last 250 not yet found), the 7500 number drops to only 1384 and the collisions drop from 86.7% to only 45.8% (634/1384).  For x=500, I get 692.5 calls to the RNG function and 192.5/692.5 = only 27.8% collisions.

Comment: Related: [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Comment: To collect $x$ out of $n$ coupons takes time $1+\frac n{n-1}+\dots+\frac n{n-x+1}=n(H_n-H_{n-x})$. To collect the $x$ remaining coupons takes time $xH_x$. So you want to minimize $nH_n-nH_{n-x}+xH_x$.

Comment: So what is that "magic" number?  Remember in my case, I want to generate ALL random numbers at least once.  This has applications such as randomly shuffling a deck of 52 cards on a computer.  In my case, I picked 1000 to make it a nice "round" number but pretty much ANY reasonable number can be chosen.  1000 or less makes it easier for a computer to simulate and come up with some good percentages.  I haven't yet implemented the split algorithm but I have the initial 1000 part working and will do the split part likely within the next 8 hours or so.

Comment: I mixed it up, in the end you have to collect the remaining $n-x$ coupons. So you actually want to minimize $nH_n-nH_{n-x}+(n-x)H_{n-x}$; equivalently you want to maximize $(n-y)H_y$ where $y=n-x$. For $n=1000$ the minimum is at $x=849,y=151$.

Comment: @Rahul, please put this in an answer format so I can give you proper credit for it.  I will have to verify it first via computer modelling though.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in reading about the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) and the related questions and answers on this site tagged with [coupon-collector](/questions/tagged/coupon-collector).

The number of random number generations is $1000$ plus the expected number of collisions, so minimizing the number of collisions is equivalent to minimizing the number of random number generations, which is a bit simpler.

When you have $j$ out of $k$ numbers left to find, the expected number of random number generations to find the next one is $\frac kj$. If we split $n=1000$ at $x$, then we expect the first $x$ numbers to require

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}\frac n{n-k}=n(H_n-H_{n-x})
$$

random number generations, where $H_i$ is the $i$-th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), and the last $n-x$ number to require

$$
\sum_{k=x}^{n-1}\frac{n-x}{n-k}=(n-x)H_{n-x}
$$

random number generations. (The second part is the standard coupon collector's problem for $n-x$ types of coupon.)

Thus the expected total number of random number generations is

$$
n(H_n-H_{n-x})+(n-x)H_{n-x}=nH_n-xH_{n-x}\;.
$$

The first term doesn't depend on $x$ and is just the result for the standard coupon collector's problem for $n$ types of coupons. The second term represents the savings from the split, and we need to maximize it. Since $H_n\approx\gamma+\log n$, we can get an approximation from

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(x(\gamma+\log(n-x))\right)=\gamma+\log(n-x)-\frac x{n-x}=0\;.
$$

The solution is $x\approx848.4$, and [a table for $xH_{n-x}$ in the vicinity](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table+of+1.0*x*H%281000-x%29+for+x%3D847..851&assumption=%7B%22FunClash%22%2C+%22H%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22HarmonicNumber%22%7D) shows that the maximum occurs at $x=849$, with expected savings of

$$
849H_{1000-849}\approx4752.53
$$

out of

$$
1000H_{1000}\approx7485.47
$$

random number generations. Thus, with optimal choice of the split point, you can save almost two thirds of the random number generations.

Comment: The solution of your $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(\cdots)=0$ equation can be found in terms of the Lambert W function, which after further approximation via $W(z)\approx\log z-\log\log z$ gives $$n-x \approx \frac n{\log n-\log(\log n+\gamma +1)+\gamma +1}.$$ For $n=1000$ this yields an okayish estimate $x\approx842.4$.

Comment: This answer is somewhat surprising and very interesting to me.  I thought it would be somewhere in the 500 to 750 range since I was thinking more along the lines of "divide and conquer".   So using this "1000" method is actually quite efficient for the first 85% or so, then after that it becomes very inefficient, so it is better to take the last 149 or so unseen numbers, put them in some new list (array if you will), and start generating random numbers between 1 and 149 (or the equivalent).  I can program this later and count up all the split points from 500 to 900 and see if my results match.

Comment: @David: Yes – it's mostly the very last part where only a few numbers are left to be found that's very costly (e.g the last number is twice as costly as the one before), and by waiting up to $849$ you reduce that cost considerably (e.g. the last number then only takes $151/1000=0.151$ times as long as it would have in the full array).

Comment: @joriki - A "cheat" one can use if using a computer is in the original array, when we get the 999th number, there is no need to randomly try to get the 1000th number, we already know which one is missing.  So technically the savings on splitting an "array" of size n would be the savings of processing an array of n-1 (so in my example, the savings vs. an array of size 999 since the 1000th random number is a "freebie").  Although in reality, it would time time to scan the array to see what number was not yet picked but I suppose that can be done quicker than waiting for a "lucky" last RNG call.

Comment: @David If all you want to do is visit the entries of an array in random order, you should just use a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: @Rahul - Yes I am familiar with the Fisher Yates Shuffle but I wonder if this "split shuffle" can beat for actual speed it on a real computer (I doubt it).    Fisher-Yates shuffle is somewhat obvious but the split shuffle point is not so obvious (to people not good in math like me).

Comment: @David: I'd be very surprised. Fisher–Yates only requires $n$ random number generations and $n$ moves – you could only improve on that if writing is much more expensive than reading and generating random numbers, which I don't think is the case – at least not in an array of $1000$ numbers that fits into first-level cache.

Comment: Maybe what I can do is implement the split shuffle with x being exactly 849 and check the relative speed of it vs. x=1000 (no split).  That would be an interesting benchmark test.  The math on this problem was very interesting thank you.

Comment: I got the benchmark for the x=1000 method.  I used an interpreted language (not compiled) , and used a fairly slow laptop computer.  10,000 iterations (of finding all 1000 numbers randomly) took about 127 seconds.  Next I will try the split at x=849 but to be fair, I will include the time to copy out the remaining (unchosen) 151 numbers into a secondary array and of course pick all of those randomly too.

Comment: @David: The Fisher-Yates shuffle is conceptually equivalent to performing your split immediately after selecting the very first random number, and then recursing on the remaining $n-1$ numbers. So yes, the "food for thought" you mentioned in your question is correct, and Fisher-Yates is that idea taken to its logical conclusion.

Comment: @Rahul: That's true for the number of random number generations, but not for the number of read/write operations.

Comment: The thing is, it seems like the technique I described would be faster than Fisher-Yates at the beginning, when very few random numbers have been chosen.  However, that performance degrades as more and more are chosen.  The split at 849 ran MUCH faster than no split on my laptop computer using an interpreted language, however, there is no guarantee splitting there is optimal for my setup.  Mathematically it may be optimal.  One of my motivations for examining this problem was to try to get a faster way to "shuffle" 52 cards on a computer, but also to learn the math behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this answer can be found fairly easily on a computer just by starting with no split, and then finding the split position that yields the smallest number of collisions.  This can be found iteratively.  However, one thing I noticed by implementing the no split solution is that it is efficient (as far as runtime and ease of coding), to just get the first unique 996 random numbers, then choose a random number from 1 to 24 (or 0 to 23), and just use that to determine the order of the last 4 "missing" numbers (out of the original 1000).  That alone speeds it up by about 30% but even that did not beat the runtime speed of the Fisher-Yates algorithm.

I still have to try implementing the split at x=849 and time it.